# Solution for copying fields between SQLite records

Tags: windows-7, sqlite

How can I copy and paste multiple selected fields between SQLite records in a single operation?

Copy

[image]

Paste

[image]

I've tried a number of SQLite tools inc. SQLite Expert, SQLiteSpy, SQLite Database Browser, and none come even close.

Comment: not clear what you try to achieve, maybe some example.

Comment: @jet, example added.

Comment: As in, replace row 6 with row 5?